# Columns are not defined for this connection manager

Tags: ssis, msbi

When I open my flat file connection manager, I see a warning message:

> Columns are not defined for this connection manager

How do I solve this issue, or is it even something I need to worry about?

[image: Screenshot of warning message in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 4):

Click "Columns" in the pane on the left and define the columns of your flat file.

Comment: I have the same problem - do you have to manually specify all the columns in my new CSV destination file, is there no way to set the columns to be replicated from the columns in the SQL source?

Comment: This question is about a flat file Source.   Off the top of my head, I can't remember if it's the same for a Destination.

Comment: I have worked it out - to keep the source columns in a flat file you must connect the source to the flat file destination component first and then create the connection manager from within the flat file destination component, rather than beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing an "online" course and during the steps of importing a flat file I also encountered it. I could not get it to work initially. Then I aborted the import and tried again and used the `"` as text qualifier (even though the columns in the file are separated). It worked and I could see the correct columns in preview.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might sound dumb but in my case, I accidently saved the file as xlsb instead of csv.  Saving the file as the correct file type resolved issue.